# How to get the custom @ControllerAdvice exception in RestTemplate?

Tags: spring, rest, exception

I am using a @ControllerAdvice to throw a custom exception from my rest service:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionTranslator {

    @ExceptionHandler(PersonNotFoundException.class)
    public void handlePersonNotFoundException(PersonNotFoundException ex, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), "The requested person: '" + ex.getId() + "' was not found");
     }

    @ExceptionHandler(NonExistingPersonException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public PersonNotFoundExceptionVM handlePersonNotFoundException(NonExistingPersonException ex) {
         return new PersonNotFoundExceptionVM(ErrorConstants.PERSON_DOES_NOT_EXIST, "The person with id '" + ex.getId() + "' does not exist");
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ForbiddenException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
    @ResponseBody
    public ForbiddenExceptionVM handleForbiddenException(ForbiddenException ex){
      return new ForbiddenExceptionVM(ErrorConstants.ACCESS_FORBIDDEN, ex.getExtraInfo(), 3);
    }
  }
```

When invoking the service using RestTemplate, is there a way to receive my PersonNotFoundExceptionVM custom exception object? I understand I can use the CustomResponseErrorHandler on the RestTemplate, but in there I only have access to the body returned by the ClientHttpResponse. Do I have to parse the body in order to get the PersonNotFoundExceptionVM fields? What is the best practice handling the errors from a REST service?

Comment: the best way to do is to wrap your exception into a Custom Object and send this object back as the body of the reponse using ResponseEntity. Something like this 
`return ResponseEntity.status(Statu_You_want_to_Return).body(customObject)` this customObject has your exception wrapped inside it